# Is it possible to set listbox datasource to List<Tuple<string, string, int>> Item1 only?

Tags: c#, list, tuples, datasource

I have

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static List<Tuple<string, string, int>> PopFile;
}
```

and I'm trying to use PopFile as a datasource to listbox

```
listBox1.DataSource = GlobalVariables.PopFile;
```

The problem is that it obviously adds ([string], [string], [int]) to the listbox but I want to add only the first items of tuples. Is that possible?

I could use

```
foreach (Tuple<string, string, int> i in GlobalVariables.PopFile)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(i.Item1);
}
```

but I'd prefer .DataSource.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET WebForms or WinForms? Use the `ListBox.DisplayMember` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listBox1.DataSource = GlobalVariables.PopFile;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item1";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Item3";   // optional
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you can't really avoid looping through and either individually adding your data from your tuple object or creating a new object to bind to the listbox.

Listbox simply doesn't have the input parameters to take in a tuple object unless you extend the Listbox object yourself to be able to handle it appropriately, but even then you will still have to do something similar to your loop above.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ might come in handy...

```
listBox1.DataSource = GlobalVariables.PopFile.Select(t => t.Item1).ToList()
```

Comment: List has more efficient method for that `.PopFile.ConvertAll(t => t.Item1);`