# How can I bind a collection of C# 7.0 tuple type values to a System.Windows.Forms.Listbox and set the display member to one of the elements?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tuples, c#-7.0

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Listbox` and a collection of tuple type values I've created.  That is, [the new tuple type introduced in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).  I'm trying to bind the collection to the `Listbox` and set the `DisplayMember` to one of the elements in the tuple.  Here's an example:

```
var l = new List<(string name, int ID)>()
{
    ("Bob", 1),
    ("Mary", 2),
    ("Beth", 3)
};

listBox1.DataSource = l;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

That doesn't work, though.  With the older-style `Tuple<T>` you could supposedly do what's described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556045/2704659):

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item1";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Item3";   // optional
```

That doesn't work either.  Here's what I'm seeing in both cases:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ivan's answer, definitely describes the case. As a workaround you can use [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of `ListBox` to show `name` filed:

```
private void listBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = (((string name, int ID))e.ListItem).name;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately C#7 value tuples cannot be used for data binding because they use [fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt744804(v=vs.110).aspx), while Windows Forms standard data binding works only with *properties*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Ivan.