# List of Tuples unable to format for a combo-box Display

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tuples

hello have a combo box that i need to put in a list  of tuple values however i only want the first item of each.

```
        List<Tuple<string, decimal, string>> SourceData= new List<Tuple<string, decimal, string>>()

        ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(sourceData,null);
        for (int i = 0; i < SourceData.Count; i++)
        {
            ComboBox.DisplayMember = SourceData[i].Item1.ToString();

        }
```

however this returns the full values as

```
{string,decimal,string}
{string,decimal,string}
```

*except as the real data.

How can i get it to be just the first string?

**EDIT**

My current working solution is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SourceData.Count; i++)
{
    ComboBox.DisplayMember = SourceData.ToDataTable().Columns[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776022/how-can-i-bind-a-collection-of-c-sharp-7-0-tuple-type-values-to-a-system-windows) why it is by design; cannot change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
List<Tuple<string, decimal, string>> sourceData = new List<Tuple<string, decimal, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, decimal, string>("str11", 1, "str12"),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, string>("str21", 2, "str22"),
};

comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(sourceData, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item1";
```

`DisplayMember` is a string indicating name of a field used to display, if `DataSource` consists of objects.

Comment: Although this is useful to know it still results in the dropdown showing the whole tuple not the first value of the tuple